# Jquery Sortable items not appending to the end of a horizontal list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I was hoping someone could help me identify why this Sortable List behaves so strangely.

The page shows a 'stage' (blank drop zone div) and below it, a list of words to drag and drop onto the stage area.

The problem is: when you drag words onto the stage, everything behaves as expected until you add more words than can fit onto a single row. The overspill words are automatically moved to a new row.

The new row will not accept words added to the end of it, but will only accept them in between previously placed words.

Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwellock/sd33e1bw/) that demonstrates the issue:

```
var oldList, newList, item;
$('.parent').sortable({
    revert: "100",
    helper: 'clone',
  start: function (event, ui) {
    item = ui.helper;
    newList = oldList = item.parent().parent();
    $('.word').removeClass('correct ok wrong selected');
    $(item).addClass('picky');
  },
  stop: function (event, ui) {
    $(item).removeClass('picky');
  },
  change: function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();
  },
  connectWith: "#wordcontainer, .parent"
}).disableSelection();
```

I would appreciate any suggestions as to a fix or an explanation of why this is happening.

**UPDATE**:

I have decided to solve this in a different way.

I have added a series of empty elements to the 'stage' in the STOP call:
    `$("#row1").append('<div class="spacer_cell"></div>');`

And I then force the empty spacers to the end of the list:
`$('.spacer_cell').appendTo('#row1');`

This ensures that you are always dropping a new element between two others.

It's a little crude but seems to provide the desired effect.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

Your sortable div has a fixed height of 80px, therefore you can only drop elements inside that height. The third row get seated below the 80px.

You should make the div #row1 give a dynamic height. You could do this:

```
.parent.ui-sortable{
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

(You have to remove the inline style)

a other example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtort8e/

**Update:**
For better behavior of the 'labels' you should use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`

```
.word {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This is not giving the desired result it is still shuffling the words inside the Dropable div.